# Is (bool | bool) safe?

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing some C++ code, and I'd like to call two functions (`checkXDirty` and `checkYDirty`), and return `true` if either returns `true`. I need to evaluate both even if one returns `true`, so my first thought was to use

```
return checkXDirty() | checkYDirty();
```

This looks a little weird (dirty, perhaps). Does this always produce the correct result in C++? What about C, with the `_Bool` type? (This code might end up being adapted for either language, and I don't want unpleasant surprises when I port the code).

Comment: Okey, okey. Well, I would say that this is really bad idea to have `isSomething()` functions with side effects.

Comment: @Andrey: Good point. I'll rename the functions to `check...` instead.

Comment: @MitchWheat they have bitwise OR precisely to avoid short circuit evaluation.

Comment: @MitchWheat The boolean operator won't short-circuit, will it?

Comment: Even worse. Very dirty.

Comment: @nneonneo I would say you should keep things apart, `check` should be check and not dirty check. Keep processing and checking stuff apart.

Comment: Judging by the voting on comments here, at least 50% of people get confused by the syntax and think it short circuts. Good enough reason not to do it.

Comment: @juanchopanza bitwise OR is for bitwise operations, and this one is clearly not. Save the time of future developers trying to understand what was that.

Comment: @Andrey I know that very well, I am not condoning this idea! The fact that so many people got it wrong is a good indicator as to how confusing it is.

Comment: @juanchopanza I agree!

Comment: If someone every changed the check() methods to return int, you would start getting odd results.  By using the bool temp variables, you avoid that risk.

Comment: If you work with other developers, it would be easy to overlook your intent when doing a "cleanup" and change the `|` to `||`. This is always a danger when doing things that "feel wrong".  If such a case is unavoidable, be sure to comment loudly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> I need to evaluate both even if one returns true, so my first thought was to use...

Then stop trying to be tricky and making your code fit in as few lines as possible.  Just call both functions and make it obvious that they need to be called:

```
const bool x_dirty = is_x_dirty();
const bool y_dirty = is_y_dirty();
return x_dirty || y_dirty;
```

Next, rename or break apart your functions as `is_xxx_dirty` really should not be producing side effects.  Your code is harder to maintain as a result

Comment: I renamed them to `check*` because `is*` was misleading. Thanks.

Comment: @nneonneo: I would say that is still misleading.  I would not expect either of those functions to produce side effects.

Comment: +1 I once tried the same hack with `|` and forgot the order of evaluation mattered to my code.

Comment: @R..: A very, very good reason to avoid `|` for this purpose. Thanks!

Comment: i would add `const` for those variables, just as a generally good habit

Comment: This is good advice but doesn't really answer the question: "*Does this always produce the correct result in C++? What about C, with the `_Bool` type?*"

Comment: @ildjarn: Ah... I guess I did kind of skip over that.

Answer (score 8):

As long as the values are not indeterminate, it's technically OK to use the bitwise operators. However, since that's fraught with problems as a *general* coding habit, I would instead just write a little inline OR-function, and let the compiler optimize. The compiler is good at optimizing, so, let it.

```
return eitherOrBothTrue( checkXDirty(), checkYDirty() );
```

Or perhaps, if you're bold and dare to take on the challenge of explaining the code to those who will maintain it,

```
return !bothFalse( checkXDirty(), checkYDirty() );
```

Or now that I read @EdS' answer, is perhaps equally good to just store the values in variables, but do then add `const`, like this:

```
bool const xIsDirty = checkXDirty();
bool const yIsDirty = checkYDirty();
return xIsDirty || yIsDirty;
```